# OpenGL ES 2.0 Grid Lines With Triangle Strip

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I need to draw a 10 x 10 grid in OpenGL ES 2.0. Are triangle strips the best way to do this? How do you draw this without drawing the diagonal lines? All of the searches that I come up with show grid lines with the diagonals drawn, but this defeats the purpose.

I've drawn the grid just using a bunch of lines, but I'm having trouble transforming it as a unit. Is this the right approach, but I'm not executing it correctly? Or is there a better way, like triangle strips? Thanks!

```
    // draw the horizontal gridlines
    for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
        modelViewMatrixRight = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 1.0f/11.0f*(float)i - 0.5f, -2.0f);
//        modelViewMatrixRight = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrixRight, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45.0f), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrixRight, modelViewMatrixRight);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);
        glUniform4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_VECTOR], 1, _color);        

        glBindVertexArrayOES( [my_line[i] getVertexArray] ); // make this line the current object
        [my_line[i] render];
    }

    // draw the vertical gridlines
    for (i=12; i<24; i++) {
        modelViewMatrixRight = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.5f - 1.0f/11.0f * (float) (i-12), 0.0f, -2.0f);
        modelViewMatrixRight = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrixRight, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        modelViewMatrixRight = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrixRight, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


        _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrixRight, modelViewMatrixRight);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);
        glUniform4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_VECTOR], 1, _color);

        glBindVertexArrayOES( [my_line[i] getVertexArray] ); // make this line the current object
        [my_line[i] render];

    }
```

Comment: Obviously drawing it as triangles won't cut it. Just draw as a bunch of lines, it's such a minimal load it doesn't matter, really.

Comment: I'm not concerned about performance. I just can't get my 24 individual lines to move as a group. I can get the grid drawn on the xy plane, but when I go to rotate it, etc. the whole thing blows up.

Comment: I would construct a whole batch offline and then draw it with one drawcall without all those matrix transformations.

Comment: Yes. That works much better. A little laborious to write out the vertices, but it works and is probably better performance. Thanks very much!